# A question on python GIL

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

Does the presence of python GIL imply that in python multi threading the **same** operation is not so different from repeating it in a single thread?.

For example, If I need to upload two files, what is the advantage of doing them in two threads instead of uploading them one after another?.

I tried a big math operation in both ways. But they seem to take almost equal time to complete.

This seems to be unclear to me. Can someone help me on this?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python's threads get a slightly worse rap than they deserve. There are three (well, 2.5) cases where they actually get you benefits:

- If non-Python code (e.g. a C library, the kernel, etc.) is running, other Python threads can continue executing. It's only pure Python code that can't run in two threads at once. So if you're doing disk or network I/O, threads can indeed buy you something, as most of the time is spent outside of Python itself.
- The GIL is not actually part of *Python*, it's an implementation detail of *CPython* (the "reference" implementation that the core Python devs work on, and that you usually get if you just run "python" on your Linux box or something.

  Jython, IronPython, and any other reimplementations of Python generally do *not* have a GIL, and multiple pure-Python threads *can* execute simultaneously.
- The 0.5 case: Even if you're entirely pure-Python and see little or no performance benefit from threading, some problems are really convenient in terms of developer time and difficulty to solve with threads. This depends in part on the developer, too, of course.

Comment: Sure, the GIL is only a problem in CPython. Though I can't really imagine somebody moving to Jython or IronPython just because of that when there are better ways to get around it.

Comment: There's also Unladen Swallow, which is Google's project to build a fast replacement for CPython.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the library you're using. The GIL is meant to prevent Python objects and its internal data structures to be changed at the same time. If you're doing an upload, the library you use to do the actual upload might release the GIL while it's waiting for the actual HTTP request to complete (I would assume that is the case with the HTTP modules in the standard library, but I didn't check).

As a side note, if you really want to have things running in parallel, just **use multiple processes**. It will save you a lot of trouble and you'll end up with better code (more robust, more scalable, and most probably better structured).

Comment: Should also mention that multiprocessing is the gateway to scaling across multiple machines anyway.  Threads cannot get you there.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the native code module that's executing. Native modules can release the GIL and then go off and do their own thing allowing another thread to lock the GIL. The GIL is normally held while code, both python and native, are operating on python objects. If you want more detail you'll probably need to go and read quite a bit about it. :)

See: 
[What is a global interpreter lock (GIL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-a-global-interpreter-lock-gil) and [Thread State and the Global Interpreter Lock](http://www.python.org/doc/2.4/api/threads.html)

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is a concept where two are more tasks need be completed simultaneously, for example, I have word processor in this application there are N numbers of a parallel task have to work. Like listening to keyboard, formatting input text, sending a formatted text to display unit. In this context with sequential processing, it is time-consuming and one task has to wait till the next task completion. So we put these tasks in threads and simultaneously complete the task. Three threads are always up and waiting for the inputs to arrive, then take that input and produce the output simultaneously.

So multi-threading works faster if we have multi-core and processors. But in reality with single processors, threads will work one after the other, but we feel it's executing with greater speed, Actually, one instruction executes at a time and a processor can execute billions of instructions at a time. So the computer creates illusion that multi-task or thread working parallel. It just an illusion.